# cofinite subspaces in weak* topology

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, topological-vector-spaces, hopf-algebras

I am learning hopf algebras by D.E Radford, questions about cofiniteness occur to me but I can't find out the answers.

My question is

> Let $U$ be a vector space over a field $k$. **Is there any subspace $I$ of $U^*$ such that $I$ is cofinite but not closed ?**

The definition of closedness is given as below:

Suppose $V$ is a subset of $U$ and $X$ is a subset of $U^*$.
Write
$V^\perp = \{u^∗ \in U^∗ | u^∗(V ) = (0)\}$
and
$X^\perp = \{u ∈ U | X(u) = (0)\}$.

**A subspace X of $U^*$ is said to be closed if $X = X^{⊥⊥}$.**

---

My quesiton came from some statements of closedness:

> **Corollary 1.3.9**$\ $ Fnite dimensional subspaces of $U^*$ are closed.
>
> **Proposition 1.3.12**$\ $ Let $I$,$J$ be cofinite subspaces of $U^*$. If $I$ is closed and $J ⊇ I$,  then J is closed.

Prop 1.3.12 might suggest that cofinite subspaces needn't to be closed, but I can't think out an example.

---

**Edit:**$\ $ I restate the question since part of the original question is trivial.

*If $I$,$J$ are cofinite subspaces of $U^*$, then $I\cap J$ is cofinite in $U^*$ ?*
Since $I\cap J$ is cofinite in $I$ and  cofiniteness is transmissable, the answer is trivial.

Comment: I think I have got one example. Let $U$ be a infinite space with basis $\{u_i\}$, and $\{u_i^*\}$ be its dual set. Extends $\{u_i^*\}$ to nearly a basis of $U^*$, then new set would span the cofinite subspace of $U^*$ as required.